# SQL Server : procedure to transfer A server to any server

Tags: sql-server, procedure

There are 10 different databases and when I add a procedure to the database I am developing, I need to add it to the other 9 databases one by one.

Do I have a chance to add the newly added procedure to other databases by keeping the strings of the database on the switch case side and giving the site number along with the procedure?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
           WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'spTestProcedure' 
             AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
             AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE')
```

This is how I can access the procedure I have added and can I add it to other databases with the create or alter method, if I can, how can I add it?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE ...
```

to create(if procedure does not exist) and alter(to override if it exists).

As for running the same code on multiple server/databases at once the easiest way is to use [Registered Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/register-servers?view=sql-server-ver15) in SSMS.